# Autosize Shape text boxes in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2007

I'm adding many Shapes to a presentation which I then fill with text.

---

Is there a function with Powerpoint 2007 which autosizes the Shape to the amount of text contain? Many thanks BobJim

Answer (score 0):

Insert | Text Box
Then click ... do NOT click and drag ... to place the text box on the slide where you want it.

It should resize to fit text automatically.  If not, make sure the text box shape is formatted as "Resize shape to fit text" (depending on your defaults, it might not be)